# How to get the last seven digit of a big binary number?

Tags: number-systems

What are the last seven digits of binary from of $$\left(65^{2016} - 65^{2015}\right) ?$$
How can I calculate it?

Also, are there any shortcut techniques?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Well yes there are some observations you could make to make this rather easier. What is it that you have tried already?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What action precedes the *carry flag*?

What are the last six digits of $64_{(2)}$?

What is the last digit of $65_{(2)}^n$ in general?